# Source at the end of table and centering cells

Tags: tables, source

How could I add before title the source of the table? Also, in the first row how could I center between 2010 and provisional the other dates?

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c} 
\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
& 1990 & 1999 & 2005 & 2010 & 2015 \\
& & & & (provisional) & (projection)\\
\hline% inserts single horizontal line
East Asia \& Pacific & 48.5 & 37.6 & 23.9 & 20.7 & 11.8 \\ 
Europe \& Central Asia & 0.5 & 1.0 & 0.5 & 0.3 & 0.2 \\ 
Latin America \& Caribbean & 2.8 & 3.4 & 3.4 & 2.7 & 3.1 \\ 
Middle East \& North Africa & 0.7 & 0.8 & 0.8 & 0.7 & 1.0 \\ 
South Asia & 32.3 & 35.5 & 43.1 & 41.7 & 41.9 \\ 
Sub-Saharan Africa & 15.2 & 21.6 & 28.4 & 34.1 & 42.1 \\  [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
\hline \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Regional Distribution of people living on less than \$1.25 a day (\% of total population on less than \$1.25 a day)}
\end{table}
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

For the source, I just add an extra (footnotesize) line to the end of the table.  To center the headers vertically, I used the `\stackanchor` macro from the `stackengine` package.  The `\addstackgap` pads the stack with a little extra space above and below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c} 
\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
& 1990 & 1999 & 2005 & \stackanchor{2010}{(provisional)} & 
 \addstackgap[3pt]{\stackanchor{2015}{(projection)}} \\
\hline% inserts single horizontal line
East Asia \& Pacific & 48.5 & 37.6 & 23.9 & 20.7 & 11.8 \\ 
Europe \& Central Asia & 0.5 & 1.0 & 0.5 & 0.3 & 0.2 \\ 
Latin America \& Caribbean & 2.8 & 3.4 & 3.4 & 2.7 & 3.1 \\ 
Middle East \& North Africa & 0.7 & 0.8 & 0.8 & 0.7 & 1.0 \\ 
South Asia & 32.3 & 35.5 & 43.1 & 41.7 & 41.9 \\ 
Sub-Saharan Africa & 15.2 & 21.6 & 28.4 & 34.1 & 42.1 \\  [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
\hline \hline
\footnotesize Source: U.S. Census, 2010
\end{tabular}
\caption{Regional Distribution of people living on less than \$1.25 a day (\% of total population on less than \$1.25 a day)}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]